# How to display Screen when device goes in sleep mode(screen off) android?

Tags: android, screensaver, daydream

Hi I need to display screen when phone goes in sleep mode ie screen off mode. I used daydream but problem is, it works only when charging!

But my requirement is, even when phone goes in sleep mode(without charging) I need to display the screen.

Here is code which I tried

```
import android.service.dreams.DreamService;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyDreamService extends DreamService {
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        // Allow user touch
        setInteractive(true);

        // Hide system UI
        setFullscreen(true);

        // Set the dream layout

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dream);
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        text.setText("Hello DayDream world!!");

    }
}
```

android manifest.xml:

```
 <service
        android:name=".MyDreamService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="DayDreams">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.dreams.DreamService" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself. It is possible to turn off the device, but the application has to implement the device administrator feature via API: Device Administration

In this API there is a locknow() function that do what I want.

Anyway, this is for extending the android hardware and security features and it is very unlikely that anyone wants to control the device in that way.

What I wanted is the ability to lock the device from a simple gesture. As I dont want to make my own device manager class I check if the free application "lockScreen" is installed and launch it. It is a shortcut and an easy way to do what I want. This app must be register as device manager so it has implemented this class. It is possible to get it free from the market.

Comment: will you please explain in brief about device administration api? and also i don't want to use any third party application to install from playstore.

Comment: so if device turned off, i can display by launching the screen on phone overlay?